# I was wondering why my countdown timer is as I will describe

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, do-while, countdown

This is just a portion of my code, and I hope will be easy enough to understand. I found a way to "fix" it, but I still don't understand this:

I set my float countDownTime to 2f. In DisplayTime(), i thought the do-while loop would count from 2 down to 0, but instead starts counting down from 0 to negative numbers. I thought that it would count down and stop when countDownTime reaches 0, as assigned in the while(countDownTime >= 0) but it continues beyond that. Thanks for any feedback or assistance.

```
   // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !hasStarted)
    {
        hasStarted = true;
        StartGame();            
    }

    DisplayTime();        
}

void DisplayTime()
{        
    if (timerStart)
    {
        do
        {
            countDownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        } while (countDownTime >= 0);

        timer2.text = Math.Round(countDownTime, 2).ToString();
    }        

}
```

I made changes to it, which is my fix:

```
   // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !hasStarted)
    {
        hasStarted = true;
        StartGame();            
    }

    DisplayTime();        
}

void DisplayTime()
{        
    if (timerStart && countDownTime >= 0)
    {
        do
        {
            countDownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        } while (countDownTime >= 2);

        timer2.text = Math.Round(countDownTime, 2).ToString();
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't see where you're initially setting `countDownTime` to 2.

Second, `countDownTime` will more likely than not stop on a negative number rather than zero.  This is because `deltaTime` is a measure of the ms that have passed since the last update, and varies quite a bit.  So you should round it back up 0 if you don't want to be shown as negative.

Finally, I think you want to execute this code as a Coroutine, otherwise the entire loop will execute in a single frame, which is most likely not what you want.

```
IEnumerator DisplayTime() {  
     countDownTime = 2;
     while (countDownTime > 0) {
         countDownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
         timer2.text = Math.Round(countDownTime, 2).ToString();
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
     }
}

void Start() {
    // start coroutine
    StartCoroutine(DisplayTime);
}
```

If you did not want a coroutine, and wanted to called it each frame from your `Update` method, you can simply drop the `while` loop.

```
void DisplayTime() {        
    if (timerStart) {
        if (countDownTime > 0) {
            countDownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    timer2.text = Math.Round(countDownTime, 2).ToString();
}
```

The benefit of the Coroutine method is it usually easier to manage.  Rather than calling a method every time from `Update`, you can call it once and just let it run.  Since the looping is confined to the method itself you can use `DisplayTime` to set the initial value of `countDownTime` to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider 2 factors.

1. `Update()` Method is called on every frame. You are executing do-while loop in `DisplayTime(`) which is called from Update() so do while loop will execute many time (once per frame).
2. do-while loop works differently from normal while loop. do-while loop first executes code inside do{} and only after checks condition and breaks loop if condition is false. so (even if condition is false) code inside do{} will run at least once once. In case of normal while if condition is false code inside loop will not run.

So in your case on first frame `countDownTime` is subscribed until it will become be less than 0. (So on screen you immediately see 0 instead of 2, because after first frame its
already 0).
after 1st frame on each frame when do-while is executed code inside do is executed only once and than loop immediately breaks because condition `countDownTime` >=  is already false. So after 1st frame `countDownTime -= Time.deltaTime;`this code gets executed once per frame (without looping multiple times in do-while), that is why it works "correctly" afterwards.